# Check which all versions of cocoapods are installed

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I want to get a list of all versions cocoapods installed on my Mac. Is there any command which lists all versions installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

`gem list cocoapods`

It will list all the installed gems with name cocoapods. Eg.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
cocoapods (1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.39.0)
cocoapods-core (1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.39.0)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.0)
cocoapods-downloader (1.0.0, 0.9.3)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0, 0.4.2)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0, 0.1.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0, 0.6.2)
cocoapods-trunk (1.0.0, 0.6.4)
cocoapods-try (1.0.0, 0.5.1)
```